# ios6 how to compose 2 images

Tags: ios6, uiimage

I am trying to overlay a play button on an image thumbnail
currentl the thumbnail is displayed using :

```
if(nil != self.analysis.image) {
    self.imageView.image = self.analysis.image;
}
```

i tried to use the thumbnail as the background image , and the play button with transparency as the image, but it doesn't appear at all ...

```
if(nil != self.analysis.image) {
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.analysis.image];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteBackground.png"];
}
```

What's the best way to compose them ?

Answer (score 0):

My fault !

The coding is right...!!    whiteBackground.png is transparent ....
I have to use the display button image ....

```
if(nil != self.analysis.image) {
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.analysis.image];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"displayButton.png"];
}
```